# How can I insert new items into a grid in the top row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am inserting items from list to grid.

When I am inserting 2 items with same grid-column it's inserted one after another (which is good). But if next item is Could fit at top of rows I would like to place it there.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  background-color: coral;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 5 / 5;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='item1'>1</div>
  <div class='item1'>2</div>
  <div class='item2'>3</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/epr5atvw/

How can i move item 3 so it will be next to item 1? My list is sorted and i cannot change it.

Comment: or use `grid-auto-flow: dense;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use   `grid-auto-flow:column;`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  background-color: coral;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 5 / 5;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='item1'>1</div>
  <div class='item1'>2</div>
  <div class='item2'>3</div>
</div>
```